# Installing ruby gem clamav

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I was trying to install clamav gem for a project on windows using ruby on rails. 
I used `gem install clamav -v '0.4.1'`

I keep getting this error:

> ```
> Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
> Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
> ERROR:  Error installing clamav:
>         ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>     c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
> checking for clamav.h... no
> *** extconf.rb failed ***
> Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
> libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
> need configuration options.
> Provided configuration options:
>         --with-opt-dir
>         --without-opt-dir
>         --with-opt-include
>         --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>         --with-opt-lib
>         --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>         --with-make-prog
>         --without-make-prog
>         --srcdir=.
>         --curdir
>         --ruby=c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/bin/ruby
>         --with-clamav-dir
>         --without-clamav-dir
>         --with-clamav-include
>         --without-clamav-include=${clamav-dir}/include
>         --with-clamav-lib
>         --without-clamav-lib=${clamav-dir}/
> Gem files will remain installed in c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/clamav-0.4.1 for inspection.
> Results logged to c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/clamav-0.4.1/ext/clamav/gem_make.out
> ```

I know that there isnt a clamav.h file in the folder for gems in RailsInstaller but it updates from rubygems.org so I cannot change it.

Comment: download clamav.h  and then `gem install clamav --platform=ruby -- --with-clamav-include=[path\to\clamav.h]`

Comment: https://github.com/vrtadmin/clamav-devel/blob/master/libclamav/clamav.h

Comment: It still gives me the same error.

Comment: I have the same problem here

Comment: I ended up using linux on a virtual machine.

Answer (score 0):

On ubuntu you can install libclamav-dev with following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libclamav-dev
```